# Update xml specific value using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

Let's say i have this xml file

```
<section name="AAA">
    <Item1>FALSE</Item1>
    <Item2>FALSE</Item2>
    <Item3>FALSE</Item3>
</section>
<section name="BBB">
    <Item1>FALSE</Item1>
    <Item2>FALSE</Item2>
    <Item3>FALSE</Item3>
</section>
```

How can I update a specific value using PowerShell ( using XPath is the right way ? )

Meaning update Item2 that under section name="BBB"

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: +1 for using XSLT instead of regexes. Check this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/XSLTWithPowershell.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your XML has a root node called root and the document is loaded as `$doc`, the following will print modified document on console.

```
$doc.root.SelectSingleNode("section[@name='BBB']/Item2")."#text" = "True"
$doc.Save([console]::out)
# Output
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<root>
  <section name="AAA">
    <Item1>FALSE</Item1>
    <Item2>FALSE</Item2>
    <Item3>FALSE</Item3>
  </section>
  <section name="BBB">
    <Item1>FALSE</Item1>
    <Item2>True</Item2>
    <Item3>FALSE</Item3>
  </section>
</root>
```